# Home internet connection suddenly unreliable

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, adsl

I'm a bit at my wit's end so forgive me if this is a common topic.

I have a 4 MB ADSL line which I access in my house via wifi. The ADSL modem is connected to an Asus RT-AC68U wifi router via ethernet.

Everything worked okay for over a month, and then suddenly a week and a half ago it started struggling. It would intermittently disconnect, and in Overwatch I'd get ping times of over 1200 ms (compared to my usual range of 165-200 ms).

Running MTR to AfriNIC (my local RIR), I see worst-case ping times of over 400 ms. I also sometimes see ping times of over 200 ms from my machine to my wifi router.

I'm not a networking tech, I don't know how to diagnose and resolve this. I inherited the wifi config from the previous tenants. It worked perfectly for years. This morning I was writing down as much of the config as I could, and noticed that QoS was turned on with a bunch of rules to prioritise browsing etc; I immediately turned it off. I'm currently at the office so can't verify whether it has helped.

What do I do? Do I need to come paste my whole wifi config here?

I just don't know where to start looking. My ISP keeps just recreating my port on their end & asking me to reboot my ADSL modem. I've gone through this whole process like five times now, so obviously have little faith that it will fix anything.

Is the fault entirely on my side? Or is it possible that there is a concurrent fault outside my house that is compounding the problem?

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Process-of-elimination troubleshooting is a good way to start when you don’t know how to start. Maybe start by eliminating Wi-Fi by wiring your client to the AP or modem LAN port.

Comment: I agree with spiff, eliminate the wifi router and see if you can recreate the issue. If you can after wiring in, you should check the logs of the ADSL modem. If your ISP is recreating the port, i.e switching pairs at the head-end, makes me think they are aware of an issue in your local loop.